# Is there a way to lazy export file with ESModule?

Tags: javascript, react-native, commonjs, es6-modules

I have a project which has many files to export. For now I use CommonJS to lazy export those files:

```js
module.exports = {
  get AccessibilityInfo() {
    return require('../Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo');
  },
  get ActivityIndicator() {
    return require('../Components/ActivityIndicator/ActivityIndicator');
  },
  // .... many other files 
 }
```

ReactNative do the same thing [React Native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/6aab3f8946937c362c0820e2e7ff3b9de26fc550/index.js), so that a file is only loaded when it is imported specifically.

I want to refactor this file with ESModule, but I can't find a way to export files lazily.
Is there a way to export files lazily with ESModule?
Is it necessary to export files lazily with ESModule?

Comment: What's the exact purpose of this? Faster startup times? Not loading unneeded modules at all?

Comment: The main reasons for wanting this behaviour would have to be performance, as you've already pointed out, and dynamic module resolution (if you are creating or resolving modules dynamically). I have also used this to delay the loading of certain modules to have proper control over the order of code execution - sometimes it's the only way to achieve this.

Comment: If your UI is static then only go for this else not. as dynamic loading is useful only when you want to load your module with some conditions.

Comment: did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/61868248/8079868

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ECMAScript way of doing this is via dynamic `import()`. The syntax is basically the same and it does what you'd expect, except that it *returns a promise* (which is great - it means that the operation does not lock the thread). Your code could e.g. look like this:

```
export const getAccessibilityInfo = () =>
  import("../Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo");

export const getActivityIndicator = () =>
  import("../Components/ActivityIndicator/ActivityIndicator");
```

You would then grab these modules like this:

```
import { getActivityIndicator } from "./the/module/above";

const ActivityIndicatorPromise = getActivityIndicator();

// Whenever you need to use the ActivityIdicator module, you first need to await for the promise resolution

ActivityIndicatorPromise.then(ActivityIndicatorModule => {
  // Do what you want here...
});
```

You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports. It also lists the cases where this syntax would be preferable. If you were hoping that this was possible using the static import syntax (`import X from '../whatever';`), rest assured - it is not.

Answer (score -1):

**No,** there is not way to lazy export in react native

export does not have an effect on performance

import/require files have to make part of **JS Bundle**

**components which are alive in memory put an effect on performance**

In my point, there are three-way to make good performace

**Solution 1: Dynamic Import**

but you can load only dynamically component like this

```
const allPaths = {
  path1: require('file path1').default,
  path2: require('file path2').default
};
```

```
const MyComponent = allPaths('path1')
```

allPaths('path1') in this case only path1 component will be active

_

**Solution 2: Stop render further Tree of Component**

stop render on specific condition so further tree should not be active in memory and give not any effect on performace

```
render() {
    const {isReady} = this.state;
     if(!isReady)
     {
      return null;
     }

     return (
            <ActualComponent />
        )

}
```

-

**Solution 3:Stop extra rerendering**

you can use **shouldComponentUpdate** to stop extra renrendring. component on specifc condition only

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return this.state.name != nextState.name;
}
```